# SetSize() not working properly : selenium + java

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

i'm trying to set my browser size through the following code by setting it to (411,850) but its setting it to (513,850) for windows only.:

width is 513 instead of 411 ,only for windows.

Note : Im following this order in my code

```
setSize(driver,411,850);
driver.get(url);
```

```
public void setSize(int width, int height) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Before setSize : "+driver.manage().window().getSize().width+","+driver.manage().window().getSize().height);
        System.out.println("calling setSize: w=" + width + ",h=" + height);
        Dimension d = new Dimension(width, height);
        driver.manage().window().setSize(d);
        System.out.println("After setSize : "+driver.manage().window().getSize().width+","+driver.manage().window().getSize().height);

    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR: while setSize()");
    }
}
```

OUTPUT FOR WINDOWS :

```
Before setSize : 1050,840
calling setSize: w=411,h=850
After setSize : 513,850
```

OUTPUT FOR MAC-OS :

```
Before setSize : 1200,1005
calling setSize: w=411,h=850
After setSize : 411,850
```

Comment: what not working properly is it maximizing or not, Please describe it properly not working not says anything or otherwise you can use directly this  driver.manage().window().maximize(); for full window..

Comment: @akshaypatil i'm trying to set my browser size through the above code by setting it to (411,850) but its setting it to (513,850) for windows only

Comment: it is working fine in my PC, might be you are sending the wrong parameters

Comment: @iamsankalp89 i'am doing in this order    `setSize(driver,411,850);
        driver.get(url); `

Comment: calling setSize before get(url) function. are you following same order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check size of browser window smaller (495, 138) with selenium. you must use mobile option as code below.

```
Map<String, Object> deviceMetrics = new HashMap<>();
    deviceMetrics.put("width", 100);
    deviceMetrics.put("height", 812);
    deviceMetrics.put("pixelRatio", 3.0);

    Map<String, Object> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<>();
    mobileEmulation.put("deviceMetrics", deviceMetrics);
    mobileEmulation.put("userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; en-us; Nexus 5 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19");

    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Comment: Or you can try open new window and resize it by javascript

window.open('url', '','width=100,height=200');
window.resizeTo(300, 450)

Answer (score 0):

It is occurring because chrome has a minimum window size limit. Selenium can't make the window smaller than that. If you try to resize chrome in your pc manually you could see that it doesn't scale below a certain limit. You are setting the width and height of the window below the limit allowed by chrome. That is why you are getting a different result.

I think it is calculated from the screen size. That is why everyone can resize to the given point in your post and can't reproduce the issue.

In my PC `(495,138)` is the smallest limit.